# Download file from Dropbox using DropNet

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropnet

I am trying to download a list of files, but isn't really sure of how to proceed.
As the topic says, I am using DropNet, and this is the procedure I am trying to download the files with:

Get a list of all files in my applications dedicated folder and store them in a List as strings.

Then trying the following:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    _client.GetFileAsync("/" +file,
        (response) =>
        {
            using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path +file +".gttmp", FileMode.Create))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < response.RawBytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    fs.WriteByte(response.RawBytes[i]);
                }
                fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                for(int i = 0; i < response.RawBytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(response.RawBytes[i] != fs.ReadByte())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error writing data for " +file);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        (error) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not download file " +file, "Error!");
        });
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work at all.
Anyone using DropNet and could suggest me something that would work?

Answer (score 1):

Used synronous method instead:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    var fileBytes = _client.GetFile("/" + file);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path +file + ".gttmp", FileMode.Create))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            fs.WriteByte(fileBytes[i]);
        }
        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        for (int i = 0; i < fileBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fileBytes[i] != fs.ReadByte())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error writing data for " + file);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code to download file asynchronously works fine, I tried in following way and it proceeds without error.

```
client.GetFileAsync("/novemberrain.mp3",
                (response) =>
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\novemberrain.mp3", FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.RawBytes.Length; i++)
                        {
                            fs.WriteByte(response.RawBytes[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("file downloaded");
                },
                (error) =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error downloading");
                });
```